# REST API: Metadata goes to DB, file to storage. To proxy or not to proxy through API end-point?

Tags: rest

I'm currently planning a REST-style API. The problem I have is that the client will send one or more files, belonging to the same "document", but while the metadata is to be stored in a DB, the files are going to file storage (probably S3, in my case).

The way I see it, there are two ways of doing it:

1. Send the metadata to the API end-point, which responds with the location for storing the files. And then, in a separate request, store the files directly.
2. Send metadata and files, in the same request, to the API, which acts as a proxy and takes care of sending the various parts to their final destinations.

The good thing about 1. is that the API server will have less to deal with, so can be smaller, and bandwidth is only paid once (client -> storage). Giving a good UX is, on the other hand, likely to be harder, and there will be more state to keep track of.

With 2. it's easy to ensure the transaction is atomic, since the API server is the sole gatekeeper. However, the server will need to be more powerful, and bandwidth may be paid twice (client -> API -> storage).

So, what's the best way of dealing with this situation, and if going with 1. any problems to look out for?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have external clients, I believe that #2 is the better bet. The way to catch and keep clients is to have the best possible UX, with a simple, easy to learn and use interface. As you said, you also get to keep atomic transactions, which will save you plenty of headaches. In my experience, server power is relatively cheap, and you can always send a 202 back to the client instead of a 201.